# Is there anyway to bypass the Verizon Wireless block of the tethering?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, wifi-tethering

I have a rooted Droid X (v.1). I used to be able to use Wifi tether to connect my computer to the Wifi from my phone. Now Verizon is automatically blocking that and taking me to a page where they ask me to pay for the Wifi. I don't use the connection that much so I really don't want to pay an additional $25. Is there a way to get around this and activate Wifi tethering again or am I hosed?

Comment: So, you're asking us to abet your circumvention of Verizon's Terms of Service?

Comment: Not that I have any love for Verizon (I don't) but I don't think we (as a community) or Stack Exchange (as a corporation) want to encourage that sort of thing.

Comment: Covered at Lifehacker recently: http://lifehacker.com/5850476/how-can-i-tether-without-my-carrier-finding-out

Answer (score 3):

Get pdanet. Screw Verizon.  Lifetime use is $14 and you'll never be charged another dime. It works well.

Comment: I've heard (anecdotally) that the carriers are getting smarter about detecting tethering traffic. PDANet's days as a workaround for corporate greed may be numbered.

Answer (score 1):

Switch Carriers to one that is more tether-friendly. (There may not be one.)